# Issue using scientific notation as a parameter for Get-Date

Tags: powershell

Per this Code-Golf tip, in PowerShell you can use scientific notation to easily generate numbers which are powers of 10: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193/6776

i.e. `1e7` produces the number `10,000,000`.

If I pass this value to `get-date` (or alias `date`, for the purposes of code golf) I get a single second: i.e. `date 10000000` => `01 January 0001 00:00:01`.

Yet if I use the scientific notation, even with brackets (i.e. `date (1e7)`) I get an error:

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "10000000" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:6
+ date (1e7)
+      ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

**Question**

Is there a way to use scientific notation with the Get-Date's default (date) parameter?

Comment: Use: `date(1e7l)`.

Comment: Compare `Trace-Command {Get-Date (1000)} -Name ParameterBind* -PSHost` and `Trace-Command {Get-Date (1e3)} -Name ParameterBind* -PSHost`

Comment: @PetSerAl Wow, the l is turning this into an int64. why?

Comment: @MartinBrandl `l` is suffix for `[long]`.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl; nice code-golf version of the answer :)

Comment: @MartinBrandl You might enjoy the `d` suffix for implicit conversions to `[Decimal]` as well

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen uff, like every day I can learn something new in PowerShell :-). Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `1e7` gets outputed as a **double**, so you just have to *cast it to an integer*:

```
date ([int]1e7)
```

You can check that if you call the `GetType` method on the output:

```
(1e7).GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize

IsPublic IsSerial Name   BaseType        
-------- -------- ----   --------        
True     True     Double System.ValueType
```

**Edit:**
Shortest script probably is:

```
1e7l|date
```

This is taken from [PetSerAls comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408902/issue-using-scientific-notation-as-a-parameter-for-get-date/41408932#comment70020730_41408902) - just removed another character by using pipe instead of brackets.

Comment: I edited my answer with the nice comment from @PetSerAl and reduced one character by using pipe instead of brackets.

Comment: Actually, you do not need brackets here: `date 1e7l`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Oh, true. You should add this as an answer - the credit goes to you.